# Скрыть/Отобразить элементы по нажатию на кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

*Есть таблица:*

```
<table class="table_dark">
    <caption>FLIGHTS</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Navigation</th>
        <th>Registration to flight</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="flight" items="${flights}">
        <tr id="tr${flight.id}">
            <td>${flight.id}</td>
            <td>${flight.navigation}</td>
            <td><input type="submit" onclick="registrationClickHandler(event);" value="Register" id="register${flight.id}" class="myButtonStyle1"></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

*Рисунок таблицы:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку **Register** скрывать все остальные tr. А при нажатии на кнопку **Close**(*id=closeButton*) снова отображать.

Вопрос: как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Через jQuery и методы hide и show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как советуют в комментариях, задачу можно решить с помощью jquery и методов [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) и [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  $('.row-that-can-be-hidden').hide();
  $(this).closest('.row-that-can-be-hidden').show();
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $('.row-that-can-be-hidden').show();
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>close</button>
<table class="table_dark">
  <caption>FLIGHTS</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Navigation</th>
    <th>Registration to flight</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr1" class="row-that-can-be-hidden">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Минск Париж</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Register" id="register1" class="myButtonStyle1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2" class="row-that-can-be-hidden">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Минск Краков</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Register" id="register2" class="myButtonStyle1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```